# Jersey return plain/text or JSON

Tags: java, jersey

I've got a simple endpoint that just returns server time, but I'm confused how I can make it properly return just plain text or JSON.

Here's what I've got:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public String getDateTime()
{
    String currentDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return currentDateTime;
}
```

What I am struggling with is how to handle actually converting to JSON if the accept type is JSON?

Comment: If you have a json provider, then you can just declare an object type (such as map) as return type, and then just return it. The jax-rs implementation will deal with converting it to json

Comment: you can create a bean class for time and return its object from `getDatetime()`jersey will automatically convert it to a json, or you can just create a json like `{ "time" : "<your time>" }`  and return it

Answer (score 0):

A simple `String` has no JSON representation. You have to wrap this into an object. Double-check that you have JSON provider (e.g. Genson) in your class path.

```
@GET
@Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public TimeWrapper getTime( ) {
    return new TimeWrapper( );
}

class TimeWrapper {
    private String time;

    public TimeWrapper( ) {
        this.time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

    public String getTime( ) {
        return time;
    }
}
```

You should implement another method to return a representation as text.